# Amazon ec2 linux Imagemagick issues

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, imagemagick

Command:`convert | head -n 4`
Shows this

> Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2014-05-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features:
>   OpenMP

Then when i run this:

```
<?php 
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->readImage('test.pdf'); 
$imagick->writeImages('image.jpg', false); 
echo 'Aw';
?>
```

Shows this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/imagick.so' -
>   /usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Imagick' not found in /var/www/html/test/imagick/index.php on line 2

I added `extension=imagick.so` to my

`etc/php.ini`

`etc/php-5.6.ini`

`etc/php-5.5.ini`

I always execute this first when testing `sudo service httpd restart`

My reference: https://gist.github.com/ARolek/9199329

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
yes | yum install kernel-devel gcc gcc-c++
yes | yum install php-devel
yum install php-pear # This line installs pecl as well as pear
yum install ImageMagick-devel
pecl install imagick
Add extension-imagick.so to /etc/php.ini
service httpd restart
```

Comment: "extension=imagick.so" must be added instead of "extension-imagick.so", but otherwise it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have ImageMagick installed, but not the [PECL Imagick](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) module.

The easiest way would be to use the `pecl` utility.

```sh
pecl install imagick
```

If the `pecl` utility is not available, you can do this manually.

```sh
curl -o imagick-latest.tgz https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick
tar zxvf imagick-latest.tgz
cd imagick-VERSION_HERE
phpize
./configure
make
make test # optional but a good idea
sudo make install
```

Pay attention to the output of `make install`. If the `php.ini` doesn't pick it up automaticly, you can update the `extension` setting to the absolute path.

```sh
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-VERSION/imagick.so
```