# PHP imagemagick setup issue on amazon linux with PHP version 5.3.29

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, fedora, imagick

Not sure if this question fits SO. Please move it if it does not.

The [installation requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.requirements.php) for Imagemagick says -

PHP >= 5.1.3 and ImageMagick >= 6.2.4 is required.

**Our server version is  5.3.29, so it should be supported.**

But, when I run  pecl install imagick, it says **PHP version does not supports it** -

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
pecl/imagick requires PHP (version >= 5.4.0), installed version is 5.3.29
No valid packages found
install failed
```

I also ran  yum install ImageMagick-devel, as given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31715938/351903, and here is the output -

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                  |  13 kB     00:00
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.lug.udel.edu
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                   | 2.3 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                                                                                              | 1.9 kB     00:00
3441 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package ImageMagick-devel-6.7.8.9-10.18.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**I am confused, due this contradiction** How do I ensure whether PHP ImageMagick can be supported on PHP version 5.3.29.

By the way, imagick is already installed, and it is working via command line -

```
 convert -resize 50x50! https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png /var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/openx/www/delivery/test_sandeepan/output.jpg
```

Comment: You are getting confused "By the way, imagick is already installed, and it is working via command line." The example code you have posted below this statement is Imagemagick from the command line NOT Imagick. Imagick is a php API for Imagemagick. You need to edit your post to try and tidy up some of the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

As stated here: https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick , Imagick needs php 5.4.0 as minimum requirement,

> Release 3.4.1:    PHP Version: PHP 5.4.0 or newer PEAR Package: PEAR
>   1.4.0 or newer

I guess the requirement page you linked page wasn't updated for a long time.

The changelog state the change from the version 3.4 https://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=imagick&version=3.4.0RC1, so you could try with version 3.3.0

```
pecl install imagick-3.3.0
```

Comment: Technically, Imagick still compiles and runs on PHP 5.3....it's just not supported aka people aren't going to get any support - https://travis-ci.org/mkoppanen/imagick

Answer (score 0):

No luck with 3.3.0, 3.1.2 should require php 5.4.0+ as well but did it for us:
https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2

> pecl install imagick-3.1.2

PS: CentOS 6 (supported until 11-2020 with php 5.3.3...)